# How to write a meta data for an object (Standard Object and Custom Object )?

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli, vs-code, jenkinsfile

I want to create meta data file so that I can enable field history tracking and there is no need for manual enabling in sandbox. I want this metadata file to work with Jenkins pipeline.
I have to do it for some standard objects( account, contact etc)  and custom objects.

Any salesforce doc link that you can provide will be very helpful.

Comment: Just use sfdx or an IDE to pull the metadata from your sandbox after you enabled it to see what the metadata looks like (and so you can have sfdx or an IDE push it to an org as needed).